# What is the best sorting algorithm to implement on a GPU

Tags: sorting, gpu

I have a list of arrays of fragments, one array per pixel. The arrays are varying in size. What is the best algorithm to sort each array - based on depth - individually? and is using the GPU a good idea to start with?

Comment: If depth is integer, then radix sort can be fast. Radix sort doesn't use comparison. This means you can do same thing for all arrays at the same time. But this needs all arrays padded to same size.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Thanks. I used the thrust library to sort one big array of long ints, where for each long int, a depth fills the least significant bits, and a subarray index fills the most significant ones. This way,  I guarantee that the depths of each subarray stay within its limits. I am not sure which sorting algorithm is used by the library, but it is fast enough for me.